# How can I host a file on a LDAP server, specifically Apache Directory Studio?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am running Apache Directory Studio on mac os. I am a LDAP rookie.

I can't figure out how to host a file on the LDAP server so that when our java service connects to:

```
ldap://localhost:12321/cn=crl1,dc=example,dc=com
```

it should get a file.

[image]

In Apache Directory Studio, where can I specify the file contents?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by “file?” LDAP is a directory service not a file sharing service.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP does not host files. It is more like a hierarchical database, with each entry having predefined fields (attributes) based on what objectClass it has. Essentially it's a kind of NoSQL database.

Depending on what data it is, the program expects to find it in attributes with a specific name. Even though your URL points to a whole entry, the program will only read the needed attributes from it.

To store an X.509 CRL, create an attribute named `certificateRevocationList;binary` in the right-side of the program (using one of the ☰<sup>+</sup> buttons). Directory Studio should recognize its data type, and offer to upload a file's contents as the attribute value.

---

(You *could* think of LDAP entries as "folders" and attributes as "files", which is close to how Directory Studio shows them, but the *terms* do not suit the way LDAP works. It would be just as wrong as calling DNS domains "folders" and subdomains "files".)